# docker-compose down with a non-default yml file name

Tags: docker-compose

I have a non-default docker-compose file name (docker-compose-test.yml).
There is only one service defined in it.

I am starting the container using "docker-compose -f docker-compose-test.yml up"

I am trying to stop the container started above using docker-compose down, but it is not working.

I am getting below error,

```
ERROR:
        Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
        parent. Are you in the right directory?

        Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml
```

I understand that it is looking for default docker compose file name. Is there a way to specify the custom config file name during docker-compose down?

Comment: Are you using the same flag `-f docker-compose-test.yml` when running the down command??

Comment: @MarcNuri it worked. thanks!

Comment: Good news,  I'll post an answer so that we can close the thread.

Answer (score 217):

You should run the `docker-compose down` command with the same flags that when you started the containers.

`docker-compose -f docker-compose-test.yml down`

Comment: aaaand this should be in the official Docker docs, but it's still not. crazy!

Comment: @Sliq https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/#use--f-to-specify-name-and-path-of-one-or-more-compose-files

Comment: Most people will probably read https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/ though to look at what options are available. But the file option isn't mentioned there - I guess because it's an option for `docker-compose`, *not* the `up`/`down` commands.

Answer (score 46):

Note, that the syntax of docker-compose is such that -f needs to be **before** up/down, and thereafter -d:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d
```

If  you put -f after up/down, it doesn't work, and also if you put -d before up/down you get the help display or an error. Down works of course without -d:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml down
```

Comment: 7 years later and your answer is still good !  Crazy this hasn't been addressed.

Answer (score 21):

You can create a .env file and add the following:

```
COMPOSE_FILE=docker-compose-test.yml
```

Comment: this is awesome! it is the only choice when you want '$ docker compose build'   from non-standard compose config file

Answer (score 9):

If you use multiple files for docker-compose AND a custom name, you should write  like this:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.override.yml -p custom_name down
```

Answer (score 7):

For whoever searching for docker compose V2 (new docker compose instead of docker-compose) in 2023

> Specifying non default/standard docker compose file for docker compose v1 and v2 is **same**.

#### For docker compose V1 (docker-compose)

```
# for stopping
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml down

# for creating
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up
```

#### For docker compose V2 (docker compose)

```
# for stopping
docker compose -f docker-compose.yml down

# for creating
docker compose -f docker-compose.yml up
```

[Docker compose reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/#command-options-overview-and-help)